# need to add an error message

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary

I have been writing code that has a dictionary and gives the user 4 options

```
1 = mothers name
2 = fathers name
3 = both names
4 = stop
```

after the user gives it an option it asks for a name if the name matches a key in the dictionary it prints the desired option.
the code works all i want to do is add an error message if the user enters a name that doesn't match anything in the dictionary. my code is as follows

```
child2parents = {'andrew': {'father': 'john', 'mother': 'jane'}, 'betsy': {'father': 'nigel', 'mother': 'ellen'}, 'louise': {'father': 'louis', 'mother': 'natalie'}, 'chad': {'father': 'joseph', 'mother': 'mary'}}

x = ""
while x != 4:
    choice = int(raw_input("1 = mother, 2 = father 3 = both parents 4 = stop "))
    if choice == 1:
        childs_name = raw_input("please enter childs name here ")
        for i in child2parents:
                if i == childs_name:
                    print " this childs mothers name is %s" % (child2parents[i]['mother'])

    elif choice == 2:
        childs_name = (raw_input("please enter childs name here "))
        for i in child2parents:
            if i == childs_name:
               print " this childs fathers name is %s" % (child2parents[i]['father'])

    elif choice == 3:
        childs_name = (raw_input("please enter childs name here "))
        for i in child2parents:
            if i == childs_name:
                print "this childs mothers name is %s and the childs fathers name is %s " % (child2parents[i]['mother'], child2parents[i]['father'])


    elif choice == 4:
        break

    else:
        print "sorry not a valid option"
```

so i tried to add an error message like this

```
x = ""
while x != 4:    
choice = int(raw_input("1 = mother, 2 = father 3 = both parents 4 = stop "))
if choice == 1:
    childs_name = raw_input("please enter childs name here ")
    for i in child2parents:
            if i == childs_name:
                print " this childs mothers name is %s" % (child2parents[i]['mother'])
            if i != childs_name:
                print "sorry no entry matches that name"
```

but it displays the error message 4 times any idea why

Answer (score 0):

Because both if statements will execute for every iteration in the loop, i.e. once for every child. That's what a for loop is supposed to do.

What you are trying to do might be done like this:

```
found = False
for i in child2parents:
    if i == childs_name:
        print " this childs mothers name is %s" % (child2parents[i]['mother'])
        found = True
if not found:
    print "sorry no entry matches that name"
```

Does that make sense? However, this is a common pattern and in Python there is an alternative that some prefer:

```
for i in child2parents:
    if i == childs_name:
        print " this childs mothers name is %s" % (child2parents[i]['mother'])
        break
else:
    print "sorry no entry matches that name"
```

If you want to know more about this method, you can read [here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html) or just look up "python for break else".

In any case a loop is the wrong way to go about this. You have a dictionary, so use it!

```
if childs_name in child2parents:
    print " this childs mothers name is %s" % (child2parents[childs_name]['mother'])
else:
    print "sorry no entry matches that name"
```

Other improvements can also be made:

```
child2parents = {'andrew': {'father': 'john', 'mother': 'jane'}, 'betsy': {'father': 'nigel', 'mother': 'ellen'}, 'louise': {'father': 'louis', 'mother': 'natalie'}, 'chad': {'father': 'joseph', 'mother': 'mary'}}

# You've already taken care of ending the loop when the user enters 4
# with the break statement below, no need to repeat it here. In any case
# you were using 'x' but never assigning to it because you use 'choice' below.
while True:

    # Converting to an int is not a bad idea, but it will throw an error
    # if the user enters a non-number and that's not a nice user experience.
    # A simple solution is to stick to strings
    choice = raw_input("1 = mother, 2 = father, 3 = both parents, 4 = stop ")

    # This way you don't have to repeat the same logic 3 times.
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3'):

        # In some cases you had parentheses around the right hand side which
        # weren't needed
        childs_name = raw_input("please enter childs name here ")

        if childs_name in child2parents:
            parents = child2parents[childs_name]
        else:
            print "sorry no entry matches that name"

            # Make sure that we go back to the start of the loop body
            # instead of continuing down to the code below since 'parents'
            # is not defined
            continue

    if choice == '1':
        print "this childs mothers name is %s" % (parents['mother'])
    elif choice == '2':
        print "this childs fathers name is %s" % (parents['father'])
    elif choice == '3':
        print "this childs mothers name is %s and the childs fathers name is %s " % (parents['mother'], parents['father'])

    elif choice == '4':
        break

    else:
        print "sorry not a valid option"
```